# HTML, CSS - <li> elements do not float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to get all of the `<li>` elements in this div:

```
<div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Nav Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Nav Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Nav Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">Nav Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">Nav Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#6">Nav Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To be all along one line.

I have the following CSS styles for those elements:

```
div#nav_bar
{
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
    div#nav_bar li
    {
        list-style: none;

        padding: 10px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        float: left;

        width: 100px;
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
```

Yet they are underneath each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are setting the width of the div#nav_bar to 25px and hence the li's are floating but overflowing to next line because of the tiny width.

Either set the width to a larger value or remove that property.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/d4S2u/

Comment: Thanks! I managed to put that width on there by accident, not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

That's a horizontal list and there are [many examples](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/).

The simplest would be to use `display: inline` instead of `float: left` in your posted code

Comment: display:inline needs to be added to the nav_bar, not li tag. Try playing with it here: http://htmlsandbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

that cause you are cramping 6

tags in a width of 25px, since oveflow is not specified, they get to another line. remove width of div#nav_bar.